# Проблема в подключением к VPS на Debian 9 через SFTP из- за настроек iptables

Tags: сервер, debian, веб-сервер, vps, iptables

Что нужно прописать в iptables, чтобы можно было подключаться через SFTP к VPS

Comment: ничего не надо "прописывать". потому что по умолчанию всё разрешено. а если вам кто-то добавил какие-то ограничения, обращайтесь в первую очередь именно к нему.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я удалил все записи в iptables

Comment: И все равно не подключается? sftp запущен? Ошибки при подключении?